# Convert IPython 2.0 notebook to html from the 'file' menu

Tags: html, ipython, pandoc

I am trying to convert my notebook to html from the file menu (nice feature added in 2.0), but when I do this I get a 500 : Internal Server Error screen with the text:

```
nbconvert failed: Pandoc wasn't found.
Please check that pandoc is installed:
http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html
```

I've installed Pandoc from the link using the windows installer but keep getting the same error. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Where do I need to put the Pandoc folder or pandoc.exe that I just downloaded to make this work?

Comment: you probably need to add pandoc to the windows search path. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. From the Windows Start Menu, in the search box type "Edit the system environment variables"
2. select the "Environment Variables" option, that should open a System Properties dialog box that you can use to Edit the Path system environment variable.
3. Add the path of pandoc.exe to the Path system variable using the environment variable editor as detailed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7). For my Windows 7 environment, I added ";C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Pandoc" to the end of the already defined Path System Variable which you should be able to select from the lower "System variables" dialog and then click Edit... to modify. Append the path to pandoc.exe, then click OK.
4. Restart your ipython notebook session in a newly opened Windows command prompt so you will pick up the system environment variable change. To confirm that your change to the Path system environment variable is correct, type "set" at the prompt in your newly opened command shell and examine the value for the Path env var.

Comment: Make sure you catch the part where "pandoc.exe" needs to be added to the end of the filepath.

Answer (score 0):

After installing pandoc from [here](http://pandoc.org/installing.html) make sure you've restarted jupyter and the terminal instance it is running from to update the path. (Aka part 4 of user3638179's answer).

Answer (score -2):

In my case notebook server complained about a missing module pygments.formatters:
"No module named pygments.formatters"

Doing a "pip install pygments" fixed the problem for me.

I am using IPython version 2.1.0.

Comment: This question is two years old and answer is not relevant.