# Trouble downloading ipython notebook as html

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am having a similar problem to others downloading my ipython notebooks with headings as html files. at first it said that the pandoc was not in my path. I inserted the correct directory there as per this suggestion ([Convert IPython 2.0 notebook to html from the 'file' menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620321/convert-ipython-2-0-notebook-to-html-from-the-file-menu)). Now I am getting this error in my browser:

```
nbconvert failed: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is the error I am getting in the shell:

```
C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\filters\markdown.py:78: UserWarning: Node.js 0.9.12 or later wasn't found.
Nbconvert will try to use Pandoc instead.}

  "Nbconvert will try to use Pandoc instead.")
WARNING:tornado.general:500 GET /nbconvert/html/HW%202.ipynb?download=true (::1): nbconvert failed: [Error 2] The system cannot find
 the file specified
ERROR:tornado.access:{
  "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36",
  "Host": "localhost:8888",
  "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/HW%202.ipynb"
}
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /nbconvert/html/HW%202.ipynb?download=true (::1) 335.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/HW%20
2.ipynb
```

I also installed pywin32 per another suggestion. Updated my node-webkit. I am using Windows 7 Professional.

Note, it is only an issue with headings. If there are no headings, it appears to be working fine.

Thanks all.

Comment: I think that your operating system may be important for answering, would you please name it explicitly and perhaps add the corresponding tag in your question?

Comment: The error message appears in the browser? In my experience the error report in the browser is much less informative than the one printed in the shell from which you started the notebook.  If you started the notebook clicking something, then try to start it from the command prompt and have a look at the detailed error messages.

Comment: gboffi, added what you requested. thx much.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple solution. Just installed - http://nodejs.org/download/ - using the msi for windows and it worked. Thanks all!