# Can't convert ipython notebook using Anaconda on Windows

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pandoc

I have been running Anaconda for a few days. I can run a notebook by doing `ipython notebook` in command prompt. I'm now trying to convert a note book to latex or pdf by doing `ipython nbconvert --to latex mynotebook.ipynb` but I get the error `

> PandocMissing: Pandoc wasn't found.

along with many error messages. I have MikTex installed. I see `pandoc.py` in the folder `C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\utils`. What can the problem be?

Answer (score 9):

`pandoc` is not a python package. `IPython\nbconvert\utils\pandoc.py` is not `pandoc` itself, but merely a helper module.

For conda users, there is a `pandoc` package available at conda-forge.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandoc
```

Alternatively, you can download the latest release from the pandoc's [github repository](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases).

Comment: This gives me an error: `Error: No packages found in current win-64 channels matching: pandoc`.

Comment: @theQman, sorry for that. I totally missed that you're using windows. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have now installed pandoc but am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 6):

Once you have Pandoc installed you will have to add the directory that contains it to your PATH variable.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620321/convert-ipython-2-0-notebook-to-html-from-the-file-menu%20%22this%20answer%22%20for%20details.) for details on how to do that.